# Copy a directory including all contents and subdirectories

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsfilemanager

I'm making a Mac app and I'm trying to copy content and the subdirectory of a folder and paste it into another.
I've tried everything but only the files are being copied. Is there a way to do that?
I'm using the `copyItemAtPath:` API and here is some of the code:

```
NSString *partsFromString = KSPPartsFromPathString;
NSString *partsToString = KSPPartsToPathString;

NSError  *error  = nil;
manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

BOOL result = [manager copyItemAtPath:partsFromString toPath:partsToString error:&error];

if (!result && error) {
    NSLog(@"There was an error copying the file to the directory! %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: Now what's in `KSPPartsFromPathString`?

Comment: Is the Directory from the NSOpenPanel

Comment: Check https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/ManagingFIlesandDirectories/ManagingFIlesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH6-SW1 they are using `copyItemAtURL`. Can you try that?

Comment: it copy successfully but it doesnt if folder exist but i want to overwrite it and merge it with existing folder not remove it is there some code or api to do this

Comment: I've tried copyItemAtURL: and the NSLog says There was an error copying the file to the directory! The file couldn’t be opened because the specified URL type isn’t supported. this is what I've done `BOOL result = [manager copyItemAtURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileFrom] toURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileTo] error:&error];`